# unity 3D doesn't work with Nvidia and 2 screens

Tags: unity, nvidia, multiple-monitors, xinerama

I added a 2nd screen to my computer. Now unity is not working. I can only login if I use unity 2d.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give more info ? Do you have the drivers and are you setting this up using the correct dialog "sudo nvidia-settings"

Comment: Hi Mark. I have the drivers and I used the correct dialog to configure it. Ubuntu 2D works, but 3D does not. In 3D i have no menu bar, nor bar to the left nor windows decoration, etc. http://goo.gl/LmEIt . Thanks!

Comment: All I can suggest at this time is check the resolution of both screens and make sure both are set to the least capable displays settings, for example if monitor 1 is 1920x1080 but monitor 2 is only 1280x800 both must be set to 1280x800. Also can you open the dash ? press the windows key to try. Also dose this help ? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1750174

Comment: You may also add the Nvidia PPA to update the driver, this fixes many nvida issues  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates  then do  sudo apt-get update  and finally  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  You will see the updae in the output and then rebbot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works  [image: http://goo.gl/Hka5o] 
I updated to the latest drivers and updated my `xorg.conf`.

This is my xorg.conf file:

```
nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
nvidia-settings:  version 302.17  (buildd@rhenium)  Sun Jun 17 23:26:33 UTC 2012

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Acer X233H"
    HorizSync       31.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "ION"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```